# Stylized facts in macroeconomics

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, balanced-growth

Max $E_0 \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\beta^t u(C_t , L_t)=E_0 \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\beta^t[logC_t-B\frac{N_t ^{1+\gamma}}{1+\gamma}]$
$Y_t=A_t K_t^{1-\alpha}(N_t X_t)^\alpha$ where $X_t$ is labor augmenting technology.
Suppose that $\frac{X_t+1}{X_t}=(1+g)exp^{e_{t+1}}$ which means $\ln X_t$ follows random walk with drift.

In this economy the stylized facts are not satisfies. That is all growing variables grow at the same rate but economy exhibits a stochastic steady state.
Prove the above statement.

Comment: Hi on this site we have a policy where we require people to first show their own attempt at solving the question for self study questions. Unless you add that this question will be closed